# Xilinx ISE 9.2 and programming FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, spartan

Can anyone tell me how should I configure Xilinx ISE to get fastest FPGA programming speed ?

I have Spartan 3 Starter Board (FPGA chis is xc3s200). I'm not sure what's the name of programming cable, but I plug it in my computer to LPT1 (parallel port) and other side to JTAG header in the Spartan 3 board. Currently it takes over 1 minute to program it, and my project isn't that big (it's only beginner stuff).

Also, I've notices that now I need to turn on "Create ReadBack Data Files" and "Create Mask File" options. If they aren't checked, I can't program the FPGA.

Can anyone tell what are best Xilinx ISE options for FPGA programming ?

Thanks :)

P.S. I should tell you that I am running Xilinx ISE inside Windows XP virtual machine. Is maybe that what is causing the speed problem ? If it is, can you at least tell me how to get rid of that Mask file, because before I didn't create it and everything worked ...

Comment: Ok, I've figured out the part why I needed to create mask file ... Verify was turned on, and it seems that iMPACT can't verify without mask file. Other part of my question (is there any way to speed up the process) still stands :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 minute is a looong time for a device that small.

Is that including a certain amount of compile time, or does impact take a long time to load on your system?

Anyway, speed improvements can come from:

- Bitstream compression - you can turn this option on to produce a smaller bitstream, which loads faster
- Faster configuration clock (change this in the configuration software, eg Impact) - no idea how fast the parallel cable will go, but I can do 12MHz with my USB cable on most boards I've tried and 6MHz on some of them which weren't quite so well-designed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try bitstream compression :) Can you tell me how can I change configuration clock ?

Comment: Configuration clock is changed in the software which does the configuration (eg iMpact)

Comment: I can't change configuration clock frequency ... So it must be that 200kHz is maximum for parallel cable ... But with verify turned off, it only takes 30 seconds, and with bitstream compression turned on it takes 12 seconds :) So mission accomplished XD

Answer (score 3):

The full-device bitstream (the "file" you load onto the FPGA) for every given device is always the same size; it does not depend on the functionality. An "empty" design's bitstream will be the same size as one that uses most of the FPGA's resources.

Configuration time depends on the configuration mode (serial, parallel 8/16/32 bits) and the configuration hardware (FPGA, PROM, Flash, programming cable capabilities, settings, and operating frequencies).

It sounds like you are using the very old parallel cable (PC-III?); try getting hold of the more recent USB ones and you should get faster programming times for JTAG (which is serial, btw).

Comment: So isn't there any way to speed up the process ? It's faster now that I've turned of verify, but I'm just wandering is there anything else I can do. I see in Xilinx's status bar values like: Configuration Parallel III  200KHz and LPT1. Can I maybe change the frequency ? What is that frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if bit-banging is possible. Haven't tried this myself but you might want to read this thread.
http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Silicon-Devices-Others/FX2-Micrcontroller-JTAG-FPGA-configuration/td-p/41602

RRS